# Install man on FreeBSD 10.1 based pfsense 2.2

Tags: freebsd, pfsense, man

I'm running a pfsense 2.2 router. While not required most of the time, sometimes using the console is the way to go. Unfortunately pfsense doesn't come with

```
/usr/bin/man
```

I was able to run

```
pkg
pkg update
```

though. Is there some way to install "man" using pkg? If it is, where would I download the man pages for my system?

I've already read https://serverfault.com/questions/239533/how-can-i-install-man-pages-from-freebsd-server-via-console-command/239550#239550 and I will try that approach if using pkg isn't an option. The later approach is just harder to automate.

Comment: I'm sure man is in one of the packages, but I don't think there's any way to search what a package provides. Maybe you can find it by searching ports, something like `find /usr/ports -name pkg-plist -exec grep filename {} \+`

Comment: @dartonw Thanks for your suggestion. I already tried that using the search on the ports website without luck. It looks like it is only part of the base system.